# Non-greedy match in a Boost.Regex extended regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm trying to write a regular expression for the boost regex engine with extended syntax that involves a non-greedy repetition. However for any regex (even as simple as "a.*?b") I'm getting a "Invalid preceding regular expression" exception.

Simple boost::regex invocation which causes the problem:

```
boost::regex e("a.*?b", boost::regex_constants::extended);
```

It works perfectly with perl syntax, however using syntax other than basic or extended is unfortunately not an option (I cannot modify the code which builds the regex object). The boost version is 1.39.

Is it possible at all to use non-greedy expressions in extended syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer your question specifically, but if your lazy match is only restricted by one character to the right (looking for a `b`) you can do something like: `a[^b]*b` (this is actually more efficient too)

Answer (score 1):

Using the perl flavour supports this:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::regex e("a.*?b", boost::regex_constants::perl);

    assert(boost::regex_match("acdefghijklmnopqb", e));
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/629df64218b2e5fd)**